# 他人のPull Requestのマージ方法

Tags: git

ある他人のGitリポジトリrepoAに、同リポジトリからフォークされたrepoBのmasterからPull Requestが届いていました。
そのPull Requestは長い間マージされず放置されています。

自分はその機能が欲しいので、自分でrepoAをフォークしたrepoCに、repoBのmasterをマージして個人的に使いたいと思いました。

しかしrepoBがフォークされてからrepoAは何度か修正されているので、repoBのmasterをrepoAのmasterにrebaseしたものを、repoCにマージしたいです。
図に表すと下記のような感じです。

```
repoA: A → B → C → D
repoB:     `-→ E
repoC: EをDでrebaseしたE'をマージしたD'が欲しい
```

どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 1点確認なのですが _repoBのmaster_ というのは図中の _E_ のコミットを指していますか？

Comment: はい、そうです。混乱させてしまいすみません。

Comment: 承知しました！回答書きますね！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の手順で実現できるかと思います。

```
git clone <repoCのURL>
cd <cloneしたディレクトリー>
git remote add repoB <repoBのURL>
git fetch repoB
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git pull origin master # 念のため / この時点でローカルのリポジトリーのmasterはコミットDの状態
git merge repoB/master # コミットDに対してコミットEをマージ
```

> EをDでrebaseしたE'をマージしたD'が欲しい

というのと少し違うかもしれませんが、結果的に`repoBのmaster(コミットE)`を取り込んだコミットができるはずです。

Comment: とても丁寧に教えてくださってありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

github 限定になりますが、簡単な方法としては `git am` が使えます。

http://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/git/20121225171742.htm

```
$ curl -s http://github.com/foobar/barbaz/pr/333.patch | git am
```

Comment: 別に機会があればこちらも試してみます。ありがとうございます！